# imageview crashing the activity for memory issues

Tags: android, memory, imageview

I have 3 images one above the other on imageview. I've put the 3 images on res/drawable and set them on the xml. when I start the activity it crashes. When I change the drawable source on the xml, and use just 2 of them it doesn't crash. But when I use all 3 of them it crash again. the images are 4.8kb each, but it keeps memory crashing. Any idea?

This is one of the 3 ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Img_FundoVerde"
    android:src="@drawable/fundoverde"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

fundoverde is the png image, that means greenbackground, I've the yellow and red also.

Could not post the logcat.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What's their size in pixels?

Comment: Post the "fundoverde" here

Comment: fundoverde.png is 413x609 px

Comment: How are you making images appear one above the another?

Comment: Show your activity code, crash log and maybe images.

Answer (score 0):

This are the images I use on the activity:
    [Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMOYQ.png)
[Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWNWX.png)
[Red][3]

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:context="com.example.calebe.riscozero.Dados"
android:background="#A2A2A2">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DISTÂNCIAS DE SEGURANÇA"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_DadosTitulo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Img_FundoVerde"
    android:src="@drawable/fundoverde"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_DadosTitulo"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_Desabrigado"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="DESABRIGADO"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_Desabrigado"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_DesabrigadoDetalhes"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Distância mínima para pessoas em área aberta ou na direção de janelas de vidro e outros potenciais fragmentos"  />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_DesabrigadoDetalhes"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_DesabrigadoValor"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="370m"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Img_FundoAmarelo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_DesabrigadoValor"
    android:src="@drawable/fundoamarelo"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_DesabrigadoValor"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_Abrigado"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="ABRIGADO"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_Abrigado"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_AbrigadoDetalhes"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Distância mínima para pessoas em área aberta ou na direção de janelas de vidro e outros potenciais fragmentos"  />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_AbrigadoDetalhes"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_AbrigadoValor"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="370m"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Img_FundoVermelho"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_AbrigadoValor"
    android:src="@drawable/fundoverde"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_AbrigadoValor"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_Operacional"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="OPERACIONAL"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_Operacional"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_OperacionalDetalhes"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Distância mínima para pessoas em área aberta ou na direção de janelas de vidro e outros potenciais fragmentos"  />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_OperacionalDetalhes"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Txt_OperacionalValor"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="370m"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Voltar"
    android:id="@+id/Btn_Voltar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you remove     android:src="@drawable/fundoverde"
and set code :Img_FundoVerde.setImageBackround

Comment: They are over the gray background.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some memory problem. The only solution that works for me was to merge the images with the background on PhotoPaint. So this is the alternative but not the real memory solution.